# Why is wp_enqueue_style not working?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

Here's my code:

```
class BWP_PostGrid {

    function __construct () {
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'plugin_initializer'));
        add_shortcode('bwp_post_grid', array($this, 'shortcode_callback'));
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'admin_enqueue_scripts'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_bwp_post_grid_get_data', array($this, 'bwp_post_grid_get_data'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bwp_post_grid_get_data', array($this, 'bwp_post_grid_get_data'));
    }

    function plugin_initializer() {
    }

    function shortcode_callback($shortcode_attributes) {
    }

    function enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style('bwp-post-grid-styles', plugins_url('bwp-styles.css', __FILE__), false);
        wp_enqueue_script('bwp-post-grid-js', plugins_url('bwp-main.js', __FILE__), false);
    }

    function admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    }

    function bwp_post_grid_get_data() {
    }
}

new BWP_PostGrid();
```

I can't get the CSS or the JavaScript files to show up in the page source.

I also checked the apache error logs... no errors.

Comment: Is this in the main plugin file or a file in a subfolder?

Comment: This is in the main plugin file, which exists in a folder within the plugins folder. `plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php`

Comment: This function doesn’t appear to be hooked anywhere. Is that in your actual code?

Comment: I omitted that code because I didn't think it was relevant. I've added more context to my question in case that helps.

Comment: Is the `enqueue_scripts()` method actually being run? Is `wp_head()` executed? Is `wp_print_scripts` still attached to `wp_head`?

Comment: `enqueue_scripts()` is being run as far as I can tell. I put an `error_log('hello');` in there and I see it in the apache error logs. I don't know if `wp_head()` is being executed or if `wp_print_scripts` is still attached to `wp_head()`, do you know how I can check?

Comment: I can put `error_log('here');` in my function and see that it is being called. I can look at the output of `wp_styles();` just after calling the `wp_enqueue_style()` function and I can see that it is... there... in the list of enqueued styles. It is there. But I cannot find it anywhere in the HTML output! This is maddening!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was working all along. The site I'm working on had installed a plugin called 'Autoptimize' which will shove all your CSS into an inline `<style>` tag. I was trying to search the output HTML for a reference to my CSS file, but it wasn't there, because this plugin was removing it!